# Can I use AngularJs for implementing Dependency Injection in my Titanium Mobile Application?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, titanium, inversion-of-control, titanium-mobile

1. Is this possible at all? Has this been tried before? Are there any other ways to implement DI in Titanium?
2. What is the application seem in a Titanium Application which is the most appropriate place to bootstrap IOC and how? (I'm thinking the composition root should be in app.js)
3. What are the implications of having DI implemented in a Ti App considering dependency lifetime management? i.e. possible performance/memory concerns, etc.

What I'd really like to do is to register platform specific implementations of a dependency in the composition root rather than having "if platform == android / ios" checks everywhere in code. This would ideally limit the platform checks to the composition root. Rather than DI, is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first point: Titanium has a concept of modules (commonjs modules) [API link](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Global-method-require)

Second point: if you use modules you require them in the body of the controller .js file.

Third point is also solvable with modules. Module is loaded only once into memory and does not leak on dispose. I haven't noticed any performance issues with modules.